# Preventdefault working on Google Chrome but not on Firefox for <select> element

Tags: jquery

So if you try the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/LNfZT/29/

It works perfectly on Chrome but not at all on firefox. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: add a `return false;` maybe it will help.

Comment: None of my business but Why would you want to disable the keydown of a select element?

Comment: What you mean by *perfectly*? what you want to achieve? I think I misunderstood your Q.

Comment: Eventually I want to disable the arrow keys and add my own functionality, but I felt I would simplify the example to the core problem to make it easier to debug.

Comment: By perfectly I mean that in chrome all keypresses are disabled (up arrow, down arrow, ect) and in firefox preventdefault does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by a combination of factors.

The first problem is that Firefox attaches its event listener before you do, so you don't get a chance to prevent the default action.

The second is a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=291082) in Firefox where it doesn't check whether the default action was prevented anyway.

You can work around the problem by capturing the event before it reaches the `<select>` and stopping its propagation.

Answer (score 0):

just add `option` to your elements selector - and `return false;` in your code.

```
$('select[id="selectID"] option').on('keydown',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

### *[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/AQjjA/1/)*

Comment: Did you try it? I can't believe it will change anything and please, please! don't select with attribute selector an `id`!

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Let me download 12 and try it.

Comment: @Landister Download it, I'm looking how to get the older v. to work simultaneously with the updated one... :)

Comment: Downloaded firefox 12 and tried the demo even with return false and it still did not work for me.